# Nifi Tailfile single file not ingesting lines from logs file. Showing no response

Tags: apache-nifi

The Nifi Tailfile for single file is not ingesting lines from the nifi-app.log file. I see the following in error and i dont know what to do. Please help. Am using Nifi-1.13 on Windows.
Am not sure if the below erros and infos in the log are responsible for my tailfile not working. Am very new to Nifi. Just learning and doing some handson. Please bear with me.

2021-07-18 01:16:18,628 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-12 ] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Unable to write to container default due to archive file size constraints; waiting for archive cleanup.

2021-07-18 01:16:18,628 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-16 ] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Unable to write to container default due to archive file size constraints; waiting for archive cleanup.

2021-07-18 01:16:18,628 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-25] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Unable to write to container default due to archive file size constraints; waiting for archive cleanup.

2021-07-18 01:16:21,873 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-18] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Failed to capture component stats for Stats History
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at
org.apache.nifi.diagnostics.SystemDiagnostics.getOpenFileHandles(SystemDiagnostics.java:224)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.getNodeStatusSnapshot(FlowController.java:3011)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.access$400(FlowController.java:230)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController$2.run(FlowController.java:697)
at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2021-07-18 01:16:30,263 INFO [pool-20-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository

2021-07-18 01:16:30,263 INFO [pool-20-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
[Flow files[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuKin.png)

Comment: Have a look at this - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nifi-users/202011.mbox/%3CCAGPmSa1nLV__C8zfKauRMuW0MQtHg7o-BMLj1nozT0ZQvR8zjA@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: i already saw that post.. didnt help me much. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Just want to update. Although i could not find the root of the issue or could resolve it. however shutting down Nifi or re-installing and doing a nifi-run helped me fix the issue and i can now run TailFile without any issue.